# Ubuntu boot option not showing on my macbook air unless an unrelated USB is plugged in

Tags: boot, dual-boot, mac

I tried to install Ubuntu on a 256g flash drive but it didn't want to cooperate, so I ended up partitioning out 75g of my mac SSD for Ubuntu. I installed it fine, except when I hold option at boot to select it, I discovered it doesn't show an option to boot into Ubuntu unless the prior flash drive (which I formatted after failing to install to it) is plugged in for whatever reason.

I saw threads saying that ubuntu can be fiddly in terms of showing up, and I tried installing rEFInd and encountered other errors.

Are there other ways to make Ubuntu visible in the boot menu? And why does a formatted flash drive make it appear?

Comment: I don't know the mac's well enough to advise, but you probably installed the grub stage 0 (MBR) on your flash drive, so it's required to boot.  If it were a pc, I'd boot using the flash drive, then `sudo grub-install /dev/???`  (or the device you want to have boot & have used for MBR/grub-stage-0).

Comment: @guiverc I tried that, and I got ```cannot find EFI directory``` which is the same issue I had when trying to use rEFInd.

Comment: That would have worked if BIOS booted, but not with UEFI which you are using. I can't advise with UEFI esp. on mac's sorry, you'll have to wait.